# GestureDetectorCompat.onScroll is not called in specific case

Tags: android, gesture, gesturedetector

I have a curious case of GestureDetectorCompat.onScroll not being called. I have a SurfaceView for showing a custom map that implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener, and in this SurfaceView class I have two GestureDetectors, one for handling the gestures in the normal mode and one for handling gestures when editing the map. I have a variable _activeGestureDetector that I assign to the correct GestureDetector depending on the use case. This works great in almost all cases except one.

Normally I switch to the edit mode GestureDetector when I double tap an item on the map, and switch back to the normal mode GestureDetector when I double tap outside of any items on the map. This works as expected. Now I have added a function that goes from edit mode to normal mode when clicking the HomeAsUp button in the toolbar. I can see that the gesture detector is switched to the normal mode GestureDetector when clicking on the Home button, and I receive the onTouch events and the onDown event, but the onScroll is not called, even though I can see in my logcat that onTouch receives one ACTION_DOWN event and plenty ACTION_MOVE events. If I keep my finger down and moving it around long enough, the onLongPress event is triggered (but it shouldn't be, as I am moving my finger all the time).

This behaviour only happens the first time I try to scroll around after clicking the Home button, subsequent events work normally. It happens every time I click the Home button to exit the edit mode. It almost seems like an error that the onScroll event is not called in this specific case, even though all the correct events take place (ACTION_DOWN followed by many ACTION_MOVE events).

Can anyone explain why the onScroll event is not called in this specific case?

Answer (score 0):

I still haven't figured out why the onScroll event is not called in this case, but I have made a work-around that solves the issue in my case.

I have created a function to simulate a touch event, so the GestureDetector will use the simulated touch event first, and then afterwards it will work normally.

```
public void simulateTouch() {
    MotionEvent event = MotionEvent.obtain(1, 2, MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, 0, 0, 0);
    onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

When I switch from edit mode to normal mode using the HomeAsUp button, I simply call this `simulateTouch()` function, after which the GestureDetector seems to be reset so it works normally from there on.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar behaviour when I added `onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e)` override to my `SimpleOnGestureListener`, then after a double tap scroll wasn't recognised until I did something like a fling gesture. It started to behave normally after I changed return value of `onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e)` to `false`.